# How to replace all activations in a NetGraph?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm trying to replace all activation layers of a certain type, there must be a simpler way to do this?

```
iv3 = NetModel["Inception V3 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data"];
NetReplace[iv3, Ramp -> ElementwiseLayer["ELU"]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first glance

```
NetReplace[iv3, ElementwiseLayer[Ramp] -> ElementwiseLayer["ELU"]]
```

seems to do what you want